# Getting totals from tables related to a parent table - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum, sql-query-store

I have 4 tables that T2 is related to Tb1 and other Tb3 and T4 is related to the Tb2.
as showing in the picture bellow .
what i am trying to do is to get the totals from Tb3 And Tb4 biased on the Tb1 id which is related Tb2
[Sql-Query Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pHMT.png)

```
SELECT        DepartmentType.Type_ID, DepartmentType.DepType, SUM(TransByDep.Amount) AS SALES, SUM(TRANSUP.Check_amount) AS PURCHASE
FROM            dep INNER JOIN
                         DepartmentType ON dep.Type_ID = DepartmentType.Type_ID INNER JOIN
                         TransByDep ON dep.Dep_ID = TransByDep.Dep_Id INNER JOIN
                         TRANSUP ON dep.Dep_ID = TRANSUP.Dep_id
GROUP BY DepartmentType.Type_ID, DepartmentType.DepType
```

this what i have triad but it give me wrong numbers

Comment: **Consumable** sample data (*not* an image) and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: GROUP BY in subqueries, before joining.

Comment: Would you please show me how to Group by subqueries before joining , i am kind a new to Sql, thank you